# php: can't create class variable from function

Tags: php, class, variables

sorry for the noobish question.
I'm new with PHP class programming and I can't figure out why this piece of code doesn't work:

```
class Job {
    private $var1 = 'hi there';
    private $var2 = date('Y/m/d');
    public function foo()  { /* some code */ }
}

$job = new Job();
```

I get **parse error** `parse error, expecting`','' or `';''` generated by `$var2`.
Looks like I can't initialize a variable inside a class from a PHP function.
How can I bypass this error?
Thank in advance.

Comment: Have you read this: http://us1.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php?

Comment: Thanks, couldn't find anything similar since I'm missing the vocabulary :) Hella downvote anyway...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initialize it from within the constructor:

```
class Job {
    private $var1 = 'hi there';
    private $var2 = null;
    public function __construct() { $this->var2 = date("Y/m/d"); }

    public function foo()  { /* some code */ }
}

$job = new Job();
```